# Replace Component not working in Inventor 2023

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-inventor

for some reason I cannot replace a component in an assembly with a diffrent component.After selecting the component to replace, and clicking on Component ->replce, the "Place Component" workflow opens up and I can choose the component that is to be inserted. When I click open, the "Place Component" window closes but the component is not replaced. Is this a glitch in the Inventor 2023 version or am I missing something basic here ?

I tested the replace component in a a clean assembly, with no constraints, just having placed a randome number of the same components of which I tried to replace one.

Comment: This question is not about Inventor API. Please ask this questions on [Inventor forum](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/inventor-forum/bd-p/78). But I try this and can't confirm your behavior (Inv 2023.2)